# UIScrolView auto layout contraints breaking on device rotation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, swift, autolayout

I'm having a rather annoying problem with auto-layout constraints set on a `UIScrollView` and its sub views. When the device orientation changes, it breaks a constraint with the following warning:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1b1830 V:[UIView:0x7a1b0520(768)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1c5990 V:[UIView:0x7a1bcf50(1024)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a17aa70 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7a1b0520]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7a176520 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1c49c0 V:[UIView:0x7a1b0520]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7a176520 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a172620 V:[UIView:0x7a1bcf50]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7a176520 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a172650 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7a1bcf50]   (Names: '|':UIScrollView:0x7a176520 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1c5990 V:[UIView:0x7a1bcf50(1024)]>
```

I've set up a scroll view in my storyboard and it contains two containers as sub views. The scroll view itself is pinned on all four sides to the superview (Editor/Pin/Leading-, Trailing-, Top-, Bottom-Space to superview). The two containers have their edges pinned to the scroll view with Auto-Layout constraints but the width & height of both is set as fixed on the storyboard, see att. image:

[image]

The width and height of the two containers gets updated via code, once initially in `viewDidLoad()` and whenever the devices orientation changes, in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation()`:

```
    _primaryWidth.constant = view.bounds.size.width
    _primaryHeight.constant = view.bounds.size.height
    _secondaryWidth.constant = _primaryWidth.constant - 200
    _secondaryHeight.constant = _primaryHeight.constant
```

This is when the above warning appears and the constraints break and the layout goes overboard. Can somebody tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

*(Note the minus 200. This is because the right container should have a smaller width. But it doesn't affect the issue. The constraints break even without this.)*

Comment: Don't need to change height and width as autolayout would do it for u. Also that warning is when u are applying excess autolayout then required so better u read about autolayout and try out with simple sample to understand it.

Comment: If I don't update the width/height of the two containers after device rotation, they will not update their size to the screen w/h which result in them scrolling vertically and having wrong sizes.

Comment: So autolayout is for taking control of adjusting your layout. You should go for autolayout programmatically rather IB.

Comment: @walle84 The problem I have with that logic is that if something as simple as this can't be done fully with IB, then what is IB good for?! Luckily I got it working via IB now, though.

Comment: Programmatically is in case when we have complex view's then in that case IB are not that useful. Similarly just like why we take uibutton programmatically sometimes and not from IB. So all things depends on flow. Also good that it got working and below answer provided by DBD is good to go !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have constraints which pin the edges of the scroll view to the edges of the screen which works in both portrait and landscape.You also have a constraint which sets the height of one of your views to 1024.

In portrait that all works, but the moment you rotate to landscape you can't have something be 1024 height pinned to the edge of the screen on top an bottom because the screen is only 768 in height. One has to go and you can see which one gets the axe.

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a1c5990 V:[UIView:0x7a1bcf50(1024)]>
```

Remove the height constraints and you'll be fine. Why would you need them anyway? You want the views to pin to the edge of the screen/superview regardless of the size your given. Non-arbitrary values will also allow you to carry the same code/layout to other devices or as sub-views without layout changes.

Comment: Thanks for the hints @DBD, however I don't have any constraint set in the storyboard that is set to 1024 height. The only place where the height of the container view constraints is updated is in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation() as in the above code. And that would be necessary because otherwise the height of the container views aren't the same as the screen height.

Comment: Wow! Just how confusing can Auto-Layout be?! Thought I almost figured it out. Added width-constraints of both containers in the scroll view and then applied 'add missing constraints' That almost gets it right, even when rotating to Landscape. But then rotating back to Portrait and the width and height of the second container view are not updated. Time wasted on this issue: 3.45h.

Comment: Figured it out! There was a width taken from a wrong view in another related class that caused the height to mess up, strangely.